# MultipleOutputs to be of different FileOutputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write Multiple output files using MultipleOutputs. Howevere i want my FileOutputFormat to be of two different format i.e. Text and SequenceFileFormat for different files. Is there any way i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the following Link: [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html)

Use the method : ***addNamedOutput***

```
public static void addNamedOutput(Job job,
              String namedOutput,
              Class<? extends OutputFormat> outputFormatClass,
              Class<?> keyClass,
              Class<?> valueClass)
```

So essentially your code would look like :

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "Output1", SequenceFileOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
 MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "Output1", TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);
```

HTH.